# Create List<T> from IEnumerable<T> being returned from async function

Tags: c#, list, async-await, ienumerable

How to create a `List<T>`  from an `IEnumerable<T>` after getting the `IEnumerable<T>` from an async function?

My code:

```cs
var orders = await _DbManager.Orders.GetAllAsync();
```

`_DbManager.Orders.GetAllAsync()` returns `IEnumerable<Orders>` and I want to avoid multiple-enumeration but `_DbManager.Orders.GetAllAsync().ToList()` gives me that error:

> Task<IEnumerable> does not contain a definition for ToList...

What is the best solution to deal with this problem?

Comment: "but .ToList() are not working for some reason" - unfortunately without any more precise description than that, we're unlikely to be able to help you. What happens when you *try* (say) `var ordersList = orders.ToList();`?

Comment: It's works when I convert like @JonSkeet mean. But i want to do it in one-line. 
`_DbManager.Orders.GetAllAsync().ToList()` gives me that error: `Task<IEnumerable<Orders>> does not contain a definition for ToList...`

Comment: Well yes, it would - because you need to await the result of the method, and call `ToList` on that result: `(await _DbManager.Orders.GetAllAsync()).ToList();`. Note that if you'd shown what you were trying to do in the question, along with the error, we'd have been able to help immediately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```cs
var orders = (await _DbManager.Orders.GetAllAsync()).ToList();
```